# KOMA: chapter page with multiline text footer

Tags: koma-script

I am using KOMA `scrbook` with `scrheadings` pagestyle

This means that the chapter pages have no header or footer.  However, I would like the chapter page to have three-line text in the left side footer and page number in the right side footer.

What I succeeded to do so far is to put

```
\newpagestyle{MyStyle}{{}{}{}}{{}{first line\\second line\\third line}{}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{MyStyle}
```

which actually puts three text lines in the left side footer.  However

- These three lines are too close to the paper edge
- I don't know where to put `\pagemark`
- `headsepline` also appears in the header

I couldn't find `newpagestyle` examples how to sort this out.  Can you help me out?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half,open=any]{scrbook}

\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=279mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=62mm,marginparsep=3mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=9mm,headheight=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ilines,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar}

\usepackage{lipsum}    

\clearscrheadfoot
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{Title}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\newpagestyle{MyStyle}{{}{}{}}{{}{first line\\second line\\third line}{}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{MyStyle}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test name}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Now I know from a comment below where the page number should be and that the header and footer should be the same width.

To shrink the text on chapter pages you can use

```latex
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/chapter}{\shrinkthisheadingpage{2\baselineskip}}
\newcommand*\shrinkthisheadingpage[2]{\enlargethispage{-#1}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half,open=any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=279mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=62mm,marginparsep=3mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=9mm,headheight=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ilines,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=textwithmarginpar,footwidth=head}% changed

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{Title}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{MyStyle}{%
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \ofoot*{\pagemark}
  \ifoot*{\smash{% hides the hight of the argument
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}first line\\second line\\third line\end{tabular}% changed
  }}
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain.MyStyle}

\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/chapter}{\shrinkthisheadingpage{2\baselineskip}}
\newcommand*\shrinkthisheadingpage[2]{\enlargethispage{-#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test name}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Test name}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would suggest to use the same height on both chapter and other pages. Therefore you could enlarge option `bottom` to `35mm` and use class option `footlines=3.25`. Then `\smash` could be removed:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half,open=any,footlines=3.25]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=279mm,top=25mm,bottom=35mm,inner=25mm,outer=62mm,marginparsep=3mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=9mm,headheight=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ilines,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=textwithmarginpar,footwidth=head}% changed

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{Title}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{MyStyle}{%
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \ofoot*{\pagemark}
  \ifoot*{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}first line\\second line\\third line\end{tabular}}
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain.MyStyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test name}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Test name}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Original answer**

You did not say, if and where the footer should be printed on even chapter pages and where the page number should be printed. IMHO the page bottom is too small for three lines. `\setheadwidth` is deprecated, replace it by `\KOMAoptions{headwidth=...}`. Additionally `\clearscrheadfoot` should be replaced by `\clearpairofpagestyles`.

In your MWE page style `plain` is empty. If there are no other pages using this empty `plain` style, you can redefine it and use `plain` on chapter pages (default):

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half,open=any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text in the example
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=279mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=62mm,marginparsep=3mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=9mm,headheight=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ilines,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=textwithmarginpar}% changed

\clearpairofpagestyles% changed
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{Title}
\ohead*{\pagemark}% short version of \ohead[pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ifoot[\smash{% hides the hight of the argument
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}first line\\second line\\third line\end{tabular}%
}]{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test name}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Test name}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you need new page styles, then define it with `\newpairofpagestyle` and use the `plain` style of this pair for the chapter pages. Then there will be no rule below the header.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half,open=any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text in the example
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=279mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=62mm,marginparsep=3mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=9mm,headheight=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ilines,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\KOMAoptions{headwidth=textwithmarginpar}% changed

\clearpairofpagestyles% changed
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rehead{Title}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{MyStyle}{%
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \ohead*{\pagemark}
  \ifoot[\smash{% hides the hight of the argument
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}first line\\second line\\third line\end{tabular}%
  }]{}
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain.MyStyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test name}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Test name}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The page number should be below on outer side and three lines of text should be below on the inner side.  That probably won't be problem for me to change.  However, as you mentioned, there is not enough space for three lines.  Would it be possible to shrink text on the bottom of chapter pages only - or perhaps translate text a bit higher?

Comment: I changed `\KOMAoptions{headwidth=textwithmarginpar,footwidth=textwithmarginpar}` and `\ofoot*{\pagemark}`.  Now it is in principle OK, but I would still chapter header page to have more space for footer.  Can you just do that?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  First, what I find confusing that using `footlines=3.25` does not change anything visually. Secondly, I was thinking to shrink text on the chapter page to move three line text away from the edge of the page, not to increase space between footer and text.  Hopefully I will find that in KOMA manual.

Comment: And `\shrinkthisheadingpage` probably doesn't need two parameters?

Comment: The second parameter is added by `\AddtoDoHook` automatically. It is empty in this special case.

Comment: `footskip` did the trick, don't know why.  I wonder why `\enlargethispage` does not move the footer.  Also why did you define new function instead of simply add `\enlargethispage` into `\AddtoDoHook`.  Is this to get rid of extra parameter?

Comment: Yes. Maybe you want the second suggestion in the original answer but with option `b` (bottom aligned) instead `c` for the `tabular` environment. But then the footer is really close to the text body.

Comment: `b` helped, but I still need circa `footskip=18mm` to move it enough away from the page edge.